# Why are tables not being created in flask SQLAlchemy?

Tags: python, sqlite, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

This is what I have in my app.py:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, url_for, request, redirect
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from datetime import datetime

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///D:/Documents/.my projects/flask-website/blog.db'

db = SQLAlchemy(app)

class Blogpost(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    title = db.Column(db.String(50))
    subtitle = db.Column(db.String(50))
    author = db.Column(db.String(20))
    date_posted = db.Column(db.DateTime)
    content = db.Column(db.Text)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

and in python terminal, I try this:

```
>>> from app import db
>>> db.create_all()
```

Then I check to see if the table has been created using command prompt:

```
> sqlite3 blog.db
> .tables
```

Nothing gets returned, which I believe means that no tables are in the database. I'm following the tutorial [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XHGpPCYmPvI), but maybe the tutorial is out of date, so I'm not really sure where to go from here.

I am using python 3.9

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I had my file path wrong in `app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI']`... currently hitting my head on my desk because I have spent more time than I care to admit on this issue.